# How do I change the pie chart value text size?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create a Pie chart using MPAndroidChart. How do I set the text size for the values displayed on the chart pertaining to the various percentages of components specified?

In short, I want to make these labels appear bigger:

[image: a pie chart with percentage labels in the slices]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// reference to your data
PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataSet);

// this increases the values text size  
data.setValueTextSize(40f); // <- here
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(8f);
```

This will change the size of your piechart slice label.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
   PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
  // for set value of text label
   data.setValueTextSize(8f);
  // if you want change Label text 
   pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(8f);// pieChart is a object Of Piechart u can get by using findviewbyid
```